# Matlab - Poor video quality

Tags: matlab, video-capture

I was trying to capture frames from the webcam present in my laptop but the output that i get is reddish,greenish. I used the following code.

```
vid = videoinput('winvideo',1,'YUY2_320x240'); 
set(vid,'TriggerRepeat',Inf);
vid.FrameGrabInterval = 5;
vid_src = getselectedsource(vid);
set(vid_src,'Tag','motion detection setup');

figure; 

start(vid)
while(vid.FramesAcquired<=100) 
    data = getdata(vid,1);
    imshow(data);
end
stop(vid)
```

Comment: some webcams output BGR instead of RGB (or some other color order).

Comment: the output was YCbCr. i changed it to RGB but still no change.

Comment: Can you print the result of a `imaqhwinfo()` query for the `DeviceInfo` object for this device (device #1)? I'm curious what it shows about your chosen input format, `'YUY2_320x240'`.

Comment: Another suggestion is to try the `getsnapshot()` method instead of `getdata()` and just see if there is a difference. Also add different input formats for `getdata()`, like `double` and see if it's a problem with precision. I have no reason to expect that it is a problem with precision, but these are easy changes to make for testing.

Comment: Problem solved. It seems that i had to set certain parameters such as the BayerSensorAlignment to bggr along with the ReturnedColrSpace as rgb. Thanks for the input.